# Is there Taylor expansion for operator functions? What does it look like?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Suppose $F$ is a smooth operator function (function that is defined on some set of operators) and $\hat{A},\hat{B}$ are operators, such that $\hat{A}$ is invertible. Show that $\hat{A}F\left(\hat{B}\right)\hat{A}^{-1} = F\left(\hat{A}\hat{B}\hat{A}^{-1}\right)$.

It seems like if one had some kind of Taylor expansion for operator function, then the problem would be easy, however I don't know if there is one and what is it like. Could you help?

Comment: A Taylor expansion would require the operators to be bounded, otherwise it would not be well defined

Comment: What is the formula for coefficients?

Comment: Well the same as in the usual Taylor expansion

Comment: But how to compute coefficients? What is the derivative of operator function?